# Overlay views in uwp/wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp, relativepanel

I need to fix the overlay views when I resize the window in UWP.

[image: Right]

[image: Wrong]

There is a Root RelativePanel and "Made for fun..." textblock has an AlighBottomWithPanel Property

```
<Page
x:Class="Telepuz.LoginPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:Telepuz"
xmlns:vm="using:Telepuz.ViewModels"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
mc:Ignorable="d"
DataContext="{Binding Login, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">

<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="LoginResourses.xaml"/>
</Page.Resources>

<RelativePanel Background="{StaticResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <TextBlock Name="logo" 
               Text="TELEPUZ"
               Style="{StaticResource logoStyle}" 
               RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel ="True" 
               Margin="0, 100, 0, 0"/>

    <Button Name="slogan"
            Content="{Binding Phrase}"
            Command="{Binding SloganClick}"
            Style="{StaticResource sloganStyle}"
            RelativePanel.Below="logo" 
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"/>

    <TextBox Name="nicknameInput" 
                 MaxLength="30" 
                 Text="{Binding Nickname, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 Header="Nickname" PlaceholderText="Кто мы с тобой орлы или вороны?"
                 Style="{StaticResource inputStyle}" 
                 RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" 
                 RelativePanel.Below="slogan" Margin="0,30,0,0"/>

    <Button Name="enterButton" 
            Content="Войти" 
            Command="{Binding EnterButtonClick}"
            Style="{StaticResource enterButtonStyle}" 
            RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" 
            RelativePanel.Below="nicknameInput" 
            Margin="0, 40, 0, 0" />

    <TextBlock Name="authors" 
               Style="{StaticResource authorsStyle}" 
               RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True" 
               RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True" 
               Margin="0,0,0,30">
        Made for fun and test UWP by 
        <Hyperlink TextDecorations="None" Foreground="#00BDC4" NavigateUri="https://teleg.run/kerjen">KerJen</Hyperlink> and
        <Hyperlink TextDecorations="None" Foreground="#00BDC4" NavigateUri="https://teleg.run/undefined7887">undefined</Hyperlink><LineBreak/>  
        Client <Hyperlink TextDecorations="None" Foreground="#00BDC4" NavigateUri="https://github.com/KerJen/Telepuz">source-code</Hyperlink>, Backend 
        <Hyperlink TextDecorations="None" Foreground="#00BDC4" NavigateUri="https://github.com/undefined7887/telepuz-backend">source-code</Hyperlink>
    </TextBlock>
</RelativePanel>
```

---

I tried to set min size to the window but as I understood I can't do this.

Do have any ideas to implement what I want?

Comment: Could you please share the full Xaml code that could reproduce this issue? It might be more helpful to see the real scenario.

Comment: @RoyLi-MSFT Yes, of course

Comment: I checked your code, there are two different ways to fix it. The first is the set the authors textblock below the enter button. The second way is that you could give the relative panel a parent Grid which has two rows, move the authors textblock out of the relativepanel, and put it into the second row of the gird.